# How to loop through each row of dataFrame, and remove the row based on a condition

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, for-loop, if-statement

I'm beginner in Spark & scala. I would like to know on how to loop through each row of dataFrame, and remove the row based on a condition.

Comment: similar to SQL, using ```https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.where```

Comment: Hi Sam , I believe you are looking to perform some filter operation on the dataframe ?.
If yes, you can go thru the below post and it will help you

https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/working-with-spark-dataframe-filter/

Comment: Can you please add some sample input & expected output ?

Comment: I have a Dataframe called Data, then I want to iterate through this dataframe using a for loop to delete rows considered noisy data according to a condition on each iteration of the for loop.

Below is the code.


`for( i <- 0 until k) 
        {
            for (j in Data.index)
            {
         var distance = calculateDistance(centre(i), Data.rowNumber(j).select("features"))
        if (distance <= max(i)) 
                 data.rowNumber(j).drop()
            }  
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter operation on a dataframe in which you can specify a condition on the basis of which you want to filter record. Below is an example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, functions => F}


object Example extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    List(
      ("Cust1", "Prod1", "Promo1", 1),
      ("Cust1", "Prod1", "Promo2", 2),
      ("Cust2", "Prod5", "Promo4", 11),
      ("Cust2", "Prod8", "Promo4", 12),
      ("Cust3", "Prod3", "Promo9", 14),
      ("Cust3", "Prod2", "Promo6", 13)
    )).toDF("customer", "product", "promotion", "cardid")

   .show()

}
```

The output of above code is:

```
+--------+-------+---------+------+
|customer|product|promotion|cardid|
+--------+-------+---------+------+
|   Cust1|  Prod1|   Promo1|     1|
|   Cust1|  Prod1|   Promo2|     2|
+--------+-------+---------+------+
```

In the above example i filtered records where value in product column is "Prod1" as can be seen in : `df1.filter(F.col("product") === "Prod1")`

Filter operation iterates on each row of the dataframe and check the condition provided and keep all records where the condition is true.